# Calling a class protected method from a template

Tags: c++, templates, protected

I want to have a template that can access the protected method of it's typename parameter. How can I make that work?

For example:

```
class Foo{
   ...
   protected:
     int Bar();
}

template <class T> FooTempl{
   ...
   int SomeMethod(T* ptr) { return ptr->Bar();};
   ...
}
```

The reason is that I want the method `Foo::Bar()` to be accessible to the template, but not to any other external caller. I hope there's some `friend` syntax there that can make it work...

Comment: Beside access-level, It should be `ptr->Bar()`, not `T->Bar()`

Comment: Why can't you add friend directly to `Foo` body?

Comment: @tyz What do you mean? How do I `friend` a template? That's the whole point of the question:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line into `Foo`:

```
template<typename T> friend class FooTempl;
```

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong when I tried that before, but it seems to be working....

Answer (score 3):

An alternate to declaring `FooTempl` as a friend of `Foo` would be to have the former derive from the latter. In this case, since `Foo` is a base class for `FooTempl`, so `FooTempl::SomeMethod` would not need to have a `Foo *` parameter anymore.

```
class Foo
{
   protected:
     int Bar() { return 42; }
};

template <class T> 
class FooTempl : public T
{
public:
   int SomeMethod() { return T::Bar();}
};

int main()
{
  FooTempl<Foo> bar;

  bar.SomeMethod();
}
```

Which of these methods is more appropriate depends on your use case.